# How to remove adware scripts in my WordPress websites?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm getting a onclick popup ad on my WordPress website for last 3-days, I checked source code and found these two scripts in the footer. I believe this has come from a hack, rather than a poorly-behaved theme.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//go.pub2srv.com/apu.php?zoneid=1063894"></script>
<script async="async" type="text/javascript" src="//go.mobisla.com/notice.php?p=628268&interactive=1&pushup=1"></script>
```

I've tried deactivating and activation plugins one by one but that didn't helped me. Does anyone have any solution?

My website is [icidelhi.in](http://icidelhi.in).

Comment: Do you believe you've been hacked, or is this something from a theme?

Comment: Yes I believe that my site is hacked. I'm really worried, I don't know where is the issue. I checked theme functions.php but found nothing.

Comment: You'll need to clear down your website and rebuild it. Is it updated to the latest version? Do you have a copy of the site external to the server?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion halfer, I was thinking and going with your suggestion, but I then hired a freelancer and he told me that this is db injection and he cleared the db infections.

Comment: If it is a low-value site, that may be fine. But clearing down the whole server and restoring from version control is still the safest approach.

Comment: You're right.. I'm thinking about getting a single domain hosting and then rebuilt website on it and after that cleaning the infected database, so that I'll not get any downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Check your .htaccees, and index.php, somethings hackers overwrite code in these files to redirect to stores or for spamm.